# 230V AC differential amplifier design

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential-amplifier

I want to know if I am been a bit silly in the following design.

I want to measure the current going to my load using a shunt resistor. This shunt will be connected in series to the load. The source voltage is a 230V AV @ 50Hz.

In order to measure the voltage drop across the shunt, I will use a differential amplifier.

The voltage drop of the shunt will range from 40mV to 80mV.

When I connect the differential op-amp the non-inverting input should be connected to the higher voltage side and the inverting input to the lower voltage side. However, on the non-inverting input, I could have 230.03V AC, and on the inverting side, I could have 229.98V AC.

Is there even a differential op-amp out there that can accept the high voltage on its inputs?

Comment: is some part of your actual question unwritten?

Comment: @jsotola, sorry I have added more info and asked a more direct question with contexts, I hope...

Comment: Don't do this. To eliminate the common-mode voltage will be very difficult. Instead, use a current transformer. This will have the added benefit of electrical isolation and, as a result, vastly improved safety.